Azure OpenAI GPT 4o-mini-batch. Batch request with grounded data (Azure Search) always returns empty response. No errors
I was trying to utilize the Azure OpenAI batch jobs.
My application uses Azure OpenAI for enterprise data. So my grounded data is taken from Azure Search (index)
I use GPT 4o-mini. While I make regular REST API calls on the LLM model, I get proper response. Now, I tried with batch process newly available on GPT 4o-mini in East US region.
When I make a call without (Azure search) data_sources tag, I get proper response. But when I include (Azure search) data_sources tag to generate response for my query, I always get empty response.
Here is my request.jsonl
{"custom_id":"task-0","method":"POST","url":"/chat/completions","body":{"model":"gpt-4o-mini-batch","messages":[{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that answers questions based only on the provided documents."},{"role":"user","content":"Tell me the names of sisters of Diana"}],"top_p":1,"frequency_penalty":0,"max_tokens":1024,"presence_penalty":0,"semantic_configuration":{"name":"my-semantic-config"},"temperature":0,"data_sources":[{"type":"azure_search","parameters":{"endpoint":"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.search.windows.net","scope":{"in_scope":true},"index_name":"XXXXXXXXXXXX","key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","role_information":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."}}]}}
Code:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI
import dotenv
dotenv.load_dotenv()
    
client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_KEY"),  
    api_version="2024-07-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT")
    )

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
file = client.files.create(
  file=open(currentDirectory +"/resources/requestJSON.jsonl", "rb"), 
  purpose="batch"
)

print(file.model_dump_json(indent=2))
file_id = file.id

import time
import datetime

status = "pending"
while status != "processed":
    time.sleep(5)
    file_response = client.files.retrieve(file_id)
    
    status = file_response.status
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} File Id: {file_id}, Status: {status}")

batch_response = client.batches.create(
    input_file_id=file_id,
    endpoint="/chat/completions",
    completion_window="24h",
)


batch_id = batch_response.id
print("BatchId-->" + batch_id)
print(batch_response.model_dump_json(indent=2))

status = "validating"
while status not in ("completed", "failed", "canceled"):
    time.sleep(60)
    batch_response = client.batches.retrieve(batch_id)
    status = batch_response.status
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} Batch Id: {batch_id},  Status: {status}")

import json

if status == "completed":
    file_response = client.files.content(batch_response.output_file_id)
    raw_responses = file_response.text.strip().split('\n')  

    for raw_response in raw_responses:  
        json_response = json.loads(raw_response)  
        formatted_json = json.dumps(json_response, indent=2)  
        print(formatted_json)  
elif status == "failed":
    print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} Batch Id: {batch_id},  Status: {status}")

Can you help to understand if something is incorrect.
Note: My index in Azure Search has embeddings also
Additional info:
Here is the 'batch_response':
Batch(id='batch_1b692a78-8c19-454c-a90e-7ad8fd22e396', completion_window='24h', created_at=1724911650, endpoint='/chat/completions', input_file_id='file-0137f769ab9d4e3aae40d1ad42c1e48c', object='batch', status='completed', cancelled_at=None, cancelling_at=None, completed_at=1724912101, error_file_id='file-cdc16b4a-a9f1-4de3-aaac-61506e615117', errors=None, expired_at=None, expires_at=1724998050, failed_at=None, finalizing_at=1724911948, in_progress_at=1724911860, metadata=None, output_file_id='file-96ec7d4d-ce6b-4b63-aad9-2a623b1a0fd7', request_counts=BatchRequestCounts(completed=0, failed=1, total=1))
From the output, I see both status as completed and also there is failed=1 in request_count. But I dont see any error message.
May be this can help you.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/batch?tabs=standard-input&pivots=programming-language-python
Here is the answer. Batch process is not yet supported for grounding data.
